# Python Looping Confusion

Tags: python, loops, openpyxl

I seemed to have confused myself beyond repair with a looping, I am expecting a dataset to be generated which shifts right and downwards in my excel sheet, but for some reason every new row gets truncated at the end of the first row, hence my traceback error, whcih tried to read an empty cell above. I would appreciate some fresh eyes on it, because my later code is reliant on this correct output, and hopefully it will solve the Worldwide Recession, or not, but will make me a happy man. :)

```
import datetime 
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import sys
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from random import normalvariate, expovariate, seed, gammavariate
from math import sqrt
from itertools import groupby


for week in CurrentWeek:
    Global_counter = week

    i = Global_counter
    j = 52 + i

    if Global_counter == 1:

        for index in range(i,j,1):
            PlanWeek = index
            EC_D = 500.0
            if  EC_D <= 0:
                EC_D = EC_D *(-1)
            EC_PlanData.append(EC_D)
            d = sheet1.cell(row = Global_counter, column = PlanWeek)
            d2 = sheet2.cell(row = Global_counter, column = PlanWeek)
            d.value = EC_D
            d2.value = EC_D

    else:
        for index in range(i,j,1):
            PlanWeek = index
            DiffWeek = PlanWeek - Global_counter
            Sigma = 1
            mu = 0
            FC_VZ = random.normalvariate(mu, Sigma)
            if FC_VZ > 0:
               FC_VZ = 1
            FC_Error = FC_Error+RemainingFCError
            fcerr = sheet5.cell(row = Global_counter, column = PlanWeek)
            fcerr.value = FC_Error

            Prev_Week = Global_counter - 1
            ECDD1 = sheet1.cell(row=Prev_Week, column=PlanWeek).value
            ECDD2 = sheet1.cell(row=Prev_Week, column=PlanWeek).value
            EC_D = ECDD1 - (ECDD2*FC_Error)

            FC_Error = 0   
            ECPD = sheet1.cell(row = Global_counter, column=PlanWeek)
            ECPD.value = EC_D
            FCAD = sheet6.cell(row = Global_counter, column=PlanWeek)
            FCAD.value = FC_Error
            IEFD = sheet2.cell(row = Global_counter, column=PlanWeek)
            IEFD.value = EC_D
            EC_D = 0
        wb.save('RHF_Loop_test4py.xlsx')
```

My Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Darren Learning Samples\codetesting2.py", line 85, in <module>
EC_D = ECDD1 - (ECDD2*FC_Error)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime 
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import sys
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from random import normalvariate, expovariate, seed, gammavariate
from math import sqrt
from itertools import groupby

## Test Lists for testing code
lst_FC_error = []

## Using Lists and Excel
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = r'RHF_Loop_test4py.xlsx'

EC_PlanData = []
sheet1 = wb.create_sheet(0)
sheet1.title = "EC_PlanData"

EC_FC_Data_original = []
sheet2 = wb.create_sheet(1)
sheet2.title = "EC_FC_Data_original"

FC_AccData = []
sheet5 = wb.create_sheet(4)
sheet5.title = "FC_Acc_Data"

EC_FC_Data_commited = []
sheet6 = wb.create_sheet(5)
sheet6.title = "EC_FC_Data_commited"

FC_Error = 0
alpha = 50
beta = 10
CurrentWeekRangeSize = 10
CurrentWeek = range(1,CurrentWeekRangeSize,1)
RemainingFCError = .2

for Global_counter in CurrentWeek:

    if Global_counter == 1:

        for index in range(Global_counter,Global_counter + 52 + CurrentWeekRangeSize,1):
            PlanWeek = index
            EC_demand = 500.0
            if  EC_demand <= 0:
                EC_demand = EC_demand *(-1)
            EC_PlanData.append(EC_demand)
            d = sheet1.cell(row = Global_counter, column = PlanWeek)
            print "hello", Global_counter, PlanWeek
            d2 = sheet2.cell(row = Global_counter, column = PlanWeek)
            d.value = EC_demand
            d2.value = EC_demand
        wb.save('RHF_Loop_test4py.xlsx')
        print "-------------"
    else:
        #this was the original logic:
        #for index in range(Global_counter,Global_counter + 52,1):
        for index in range(Global_counter,52,1):
            PlanWeek = index
            DiffWeek = PlanWeek - Global_counter
            Sigma = 1
            mu = 0
            FC_VZ = random.normalvariate(mu, Sigma)
            if FC_VZ > 0:
               FC_VZ = 1
            FC_Error = FC_Error+RemainingFCError   ## decrease demand
            fcerr = sheet5.cell(row = Global_counter, column = PlanWeek)
            fcerr.value = FC_Error

            Prev_Week = Global_counter - 1
            ECDD1 = sheet1.cell(row=Prev_Week, column=PlanWeek).value
            print Prev_Week, PlanWeek, ECDD1
            ECDD2 = sheet1.cell(row=Prev_Week, column=PlanWeek).value
            EC_demand = ECDD1 - (ECDD2*FC_Error)

            FC_Error = 0   
            ECPD = sheet1.cell(row = Global_counter, column=PlanWeek)
            ECPD.value = EC_demand
            FCAD = sheet6.cell(row = Global_counter, column=PlanWeek)
            FCAD.value = FC_Error
            IEFD = sheet2.cell(row = Global_counter, column=PlanWeek)
            IEFD.value = EC_demand
            EC_demand = 0
        wb.save('RHF_Loop_test4py.xlsx')
```

Comment: The first row created has 62 values. Subsequent rows are only 51 values across still. I am trying now to use `try: .... except:` to convert Nonetype returns to a number, seems to be working, except some intermittent cells are blank.

Comment: Thanks, your guidance pushed me along the right path, works good now.

Answer (score 2):

I totally don't get what are you trying to compute, but here's the cause of the mentioned exception.

First of all, in your first `for` loop, in the excel file you take a row (row #1), and fill the columns in that row from column #1 to column #52 (indexing starts from 0):

Later, in the second `for` loop, when you read the values, you increase the global counter so when the exception is thrown, you are trying to read the values for the 53th week.

Solution: instead of

```
        ECDD1 = sheet1.cell(row=Prev_Week, column=PlanWeek).value
        ECDD2 = sheet1.cell(row=Prev_Week, column=PlanWeek).value
        EC_demand = ECDD1 - (ECDD2*FC_Error)
```

you could

```
        ECDD1 = sheet1.cell(row=Prev_Week, column=DiffWeek).value
        ECDD2 = sheet1.cell(row=Prev_Week, column=DiffWeek).value
        EC_demand = ECDD1 - (ECDD2*FC_Error)
```

You actually created the `DiffWeek` variable but forgot to use it.

Comment: The DiffWeek variable is used later, I removed that portion just to make it more forum friendly, but the PlanWeek reference is right.
What it should do is write 52 values to excel by moving in 1 column on each row , so you get a 'trapezoid' data table. My error occurs because it doesnt seem to want to write to excel beyond column 52 of the first row

Comment: OK, I have given it a second look. Please see my other answer